# Test API call in Onclick Function using JEST and React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I need help testing the API call in Onclick Function

```
export function functionName (a, b, c){
 const handleValue = async() =>{
 axios.get(url, {method: 'post', body:{a: "a"}};
 }

return <div>
{getvalue &&
<Button Onclick= {handleValue}>Button </Button>}
</div>
}
```

Please help me understand how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can mock your API call using jest like:

```
import axios from 'axios';

jest.mock('axios');

test('your test name', () => {
  axios.post.mockResolvedValue({data: yourSampleResponsePayload});
  // rest of your test contents such as button click and so on
});
```